# adding a mootools progress bar

Tags: jquery, file-upload, mootools, progress-bar

I'm given an application to work with, and i'm supposed to add a progress bar to a part of the application. This is a file upload form. Here's the code:

```
<input type="file" name="product_file[]"/><br/>
<input type="file" name="product_file[]"/><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Attach files"/>
```

There is no opening/closing form tags and hence no action url to post to. How can i attach a progress bar to such a file upload?

Comment: You'd have to implement a script such as FancyUpload for asynchronous uploading (via a Flash movie proxy), with an actual percentage meter. If a simple spinner is what you're after, just attach an event to the submit and fade in the spinner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just add a progressbar to to your html for this direct upload. If you need a progressbar you can use for example fancyUpload from Digitarald (  http://digitarald.de/project/fancyupload/ ) it's well documented and makes a great job. It also supports some more userfriendly behavior. An alternative would be http://www.uploadify.com/ but I didn't use it and so i can't tell you anything about this.